# Exporting Java without JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, export

I have been working with **Java** for a while, and I have made some simple windowed java programs that export correctly in **Eclipse** to a **.Jar** file. I can run them fine on my computer and other computers that have JRE. However I want to share the programs with other people who don't have JRE, and I don't want to / cant get them to install JRE. Is there a way I can package JRE with my jar or in some way make in not require JRE or some other way to do what I want.

Comment: Oh, sorry I though I looked around for similar posts, but I didn't see that one. I'll check it out and see it it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Executable java jar can only be executed when JRE is present in a machine.